# Quarto in Fedora: Missing .qmd File Option in RStudio

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, fedora, quarto

I recently installed Quarto 1.3.450 on my Fedora 39 system, following [these steps](https://quarto.org/docs/download/tarball.html?version=1.2.242&idPrefix=download-pre), but I'm encountering an issue in RStudio. When I navigate to File > New File, the option to create a .qmd (Quarto Markdown) file is not available.

[image]

I checked whether Quarto has been actually installed, and apparently it's there

[image]

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this problem? Thank you very much in advance.

My RStudio version is 2023.12.0+369, so the latest.

Comment: Probably related - https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12609
By any chance, have you tried RStudio distributed by Posit? Or perhaps even daily builds? 
https://posit.co/download/rstudio-desktop/ , https://dailies.rstudio.com/

Comment: I installed RStudio using the following command `sudo dnf install rstudio-desktop`, should I uninstall it and try the daily builds instead?